# How to do slice assignment in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow2.0

I am currently trying to perform a TensorFlow slice assignment similar to this PyTorch code.

```
input_seq[1:, :] = torch.from_numpy(stroke[:-1, :])
```

A plain item assignment like the above does not work for TensorFlow and gives the following error.

```
TypeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object does not support item assignment.
```

Previous solutions for the same problem are quite dated using older versions of TensorFlow. I would greatly appreciate any help regarding how to tackle the same.

Comment: [Are you trying to use `from_tensor_slices()`?](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices)

Comment: No, I was converting a NumPy array to tensor and then applying indexing on the same. I have shared the complete problem in detail here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73267868/how-to-do-slice-and-update-operation-on-tensors-in-tensorflow-2-0

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. You can't do numpy like slice assignements. But can do the following (Tested `tensorflow==2.9`).

```
tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

b = np.array([[6, 5, 4], [9, 8, 7]])

c = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(a, [[1], [2]], b)
```

Comment: I have tried working with tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update function previously but have been unsuccessful to find a sol. Also, I was looking for alternative approaches as I believe tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update needs tf.Variable instead of a tf.Tensor object. In case if u are still interested I have shared the complete problem in detail here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73267868/how-to-do-slice-and-update-operation-on-tensors-in-tensorflow-2-0

Comment: No, `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update` works with tf.Tensor objects (literally in the name). The example itself doesn't use any tf.Variable objects as you can see (doc: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update)