# How to do slice and update operation on tensors in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow2.0

I have been trying to convert the following PyTorch code into TensorFlow 2.0.

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    mask = torch.from_numpy(self.mask[idx])
    input_seq = torch.zeros(self.dataset[idx].shape,
                                dtype=torch.float32)
    input_seq[1:, :] = torch.from_numpy(self.dataset[idx, :-1, :])
    target = torch.from_numpy(self.dataset[idx])
    return (input_seq, target, mask)
```

My implementation of the above in TensorFlow resulted into the following error

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    mask = tf.convert_to_tensor(self.mask[idx])
    input_seq = tf.zeros(self.dataset[idx].shape,
                                dtype=tf.float32)
    input_seq[1:, :] = tf.convert_to_tensor(self.dataset[idx, :-1, :])
    target = tf.convert_to_tensor(self.dataset[idx])
    return (input_seq, target, mask)

'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object does not support item assignment
```

I have tried implementing TensorFlow slice assignment using tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update function but haven't been able to come up with a viable solution. I would greatly appreciate any help regarding how to tackle this problem.

Comment: not quite able to follow the code since it's not too clear what you want, but have you tried `input_seq[1:, :].assign(tf.convert_to_tensor(self.dataset[idx, :-1, :]))`?

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. The code is working now.

Comment: I'll add an answer in order to make it more visible if others looks for this fix

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `assign` method just like this:

```py
input_seq[1:, :].assign(tf.convert_to_tensor(self.dataset[idx, :-1, :]))
```